# Select All for Read Access and Edit Access in Profile

Tags: custom-profile

How to check all checkboxes of Read Access and Edit Access in custom profile for the all fields not manually?

Answer (score 0):

After i came out of the box, we can able to select all checkboxes for custom profile fields through running some java script in your browser tab

Inspect the browser tab and run the following code in your console

```
var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
    if (inputElements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
        inputElements[i].checked = true;
    }
}
```

It does the trick and saves my lot of time especially when configuring the profiles initially